# unset LC_* previous to ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, bashrc

In my `~/.bashrc` I have environment variables definition similar to

```
export LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
```

when I use a ssh connection some of this variables have problems in the remote computer

```
man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

how I can `unset` some variables when I start a ssh connection and restore when I close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh` doesn't copy your local environment to the remote machine. See the ENVIRONMENT section of the `ssh` man page for details. In short, there is a small list of variables that are set in the remote session, and you can put additional variables in `~/.ssh/environment`. Note that the ability to set the environment on the remote end from the local machine needs to be enabled in the remote `sshd` process via the `PermitUserEnvironment` configuration option.

Alternatively, you need to set the values you need on the remote machine in your `.bashrc` file on the remote machine.